# light box popup Should not be come another time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I load the page the popup should be showed. But when I refresh the page the popup should not be there.
'

```
       $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
       $('#fade').css('display','block');
       $('#light').css('display','block');
    `
```

fade and light class is for fade the screen and light will slide from upper side. Now if I refresh the page this light box will come another time on the screen. I have put this code in ready function thats why it shows up every time when I refresh the page.What to do make it shows up only on time at the time of page loading. Prevent it to shows up every time I refresh te page.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('wasVisited') !== undefined) {
         $('#fade').hide();
         $('#light').hide();
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('wasVisited', 1);
         $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
         $('#fade').show();
         $('#light').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will either have to set a cookie, use Serverside-Code or maybe you could go with session.storage for a plain JS solution.

Here is a example with session storage, with is the best imo:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/2Pc58/1/

```
if(!sessionStorage.getItem("lastVisit")){
         sessionStorage.setItem("lastVisit",new Date());
        alert("you are new here")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Nico its completely working.But I want to make it like when user close the tab and open it another time the popup should be there but on refresh page the popup should not be there.Is it possible to do?

Comment: @user3300870 you can handle your tabs with Javascript and visibility classes, like you would do it without this code. You just append this snippet to handle behaviour on reload. Don't mix it with your tab default behaviour.

Comment: Nico, I am new to javascript and jquery. So if you tell me how to handle it on reload ,it would be really helpful.

Comment: have a look at the answer of @Agha Umair Ahmed just replace the `alert("you are new here")` with the code you want to have commited on pageload for new visitors. Append a `else { //Code here }` for all reloads of returning visitors